# Cannot move Zune 4.0 window across to second monitor

Tags: windows-vista, multiple-monitors, zune, zune-software

I have a dual-monitor setup running Vista.  I upgraded to the new Zune 4.0 software, and now I cannot drag the Zune window across to the second monitor because of this "snap to window" feature.  I.e. whenever the mouse reaches close to the edge of the monitor, the Zune window snaps to it.   I tried the keyboard shortcut to move a window, but the Move menu in the Zune window is disabled!

What on earth were they thinking?  Didn't they test this?

Has anyone found a way around this?

Comment: BTW, didn't mean to sound like I'm bashing MS or the Zune.  I like the Zune a lot and the software is great, aside from occasional issues like this (I also have an iPod nano which I don't use anymore).  Zunepass is especially awesome, iTunes can't beat that!

Answer (score 3):

It's a [known issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/Zune/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=490011#tabs) with Zune. Check the workaround link. Should be fixed on upcoming versions.

Another option, of course, is to disable Aero Snap.

Comment: I think Aero Snap is new for Windows 7. I'm running Vista, but I guess the Zune folks decided to backport it in Vista. What bugs me the most is that they don't even have an option to turn the snap feature off. In the old days Microsoft apps used to expose too many settings... now they've gone completely the other way.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a work around. It's long and annoying, but it works in a pinch:

1. Change to the mini-player mode.
2. Move Windows' taskbar to the second monitor.
3. Now drag the mini-player to the second monitor.
4. Minimize the mini-player.
5. Maximize the mini-player.

Comment: In other words, Microsoft has left a massive bug in their software, again

Comment: I managed to figure this one out, the only problem is that now the Zune window takes up the entire second monitor... not quite what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me:

1. In Settings\Software\Display, set screen graphics to Basic.
2. Exit and restart Zune.

At this point you should be able to drag the Zune window to another monitor with no problems.

Setting the screen graphics back up to Premium doesn't cause the bug to recur, surprisingly.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 :

```
Win + Shift + Left/Right Arrow
```

Will move it to the same position on the 2nd monitor.

You won't be able to resize it on 2nd monitor but you can at least move it over there.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a good one that *sometimes* works for me.

- Open task manager. Be sure to have zune window open and accessible.
- Kill dwm.exe
- While its recovering you have a brief 'window' of time in which to move it over to monitor 2

Unfortunately you can't move it on the second screen, but its good to just get it out of the way!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe **[Actual Window Manager](http://www.actualtools.com/windowmanager/)** is for you.

[image]

[image] **Move to Monitor** - left-click this button to move a window to the monitor that is assigned in your system as next to that one the desired window currently resides on. Right-click this button to display a context menu with the list of available monitors - the menu item corresponding to the monitor window is currently on is checked; clicking another item will quickly move a window to this item's corresponding monitor.

*Actual Window Manager is shareware, try before you buy.*

My personal opinion? It's well worth the money, certainly the best window manager I have seen with great multi-monitor support (including start button(s) on the extended task bar for each monitor). Their claim "The Most Feature-Rich and Comprehensive Window Manager for Microsoft® Windows® in the World!" is probably true!

Answer (score 0):

For Zune Software Version 4.2.202.0

1. Restore window so it is not full screen, and is not minimized.
2. Right-click the Zune entry in the task bar.
3. Left-click "Move"
4. Press the arrow keys on the keyboard to move it to the other monitor.
5. Do not resize it while on the other monitor, or it will jump back to the primary screen.